# Get border-radius of an SVG

Tags: svg

Is there any possible way to get/find the border radius of an SVG?

Specifically, the rounded corners.

**Example:**

```html
<svg width="266" height="185" viewBox="-1.5 0 71 48">
    <path fill="currentColor" style="stroke: #0059dd; stroke-width:1px;color:black;" d="M66.52,7.74c-0.78-2.93-2.49-5.41-5.42-6.19C55.79,.13,34,0,34,0S12.21,.13,6.9,1.55 C3.97,2.33,2.27,4.81,1.48,7.74C0.06,13.05,0,24,0,24s0.06,10.95,1.48,16.26c0.78,2.93,2.49,5.41,5.42,6.19 C12.21,47.87,34,48,34,48s21.79-0.13,27.1-1.55c2.93-0.78,4.64-3.26,5.42-6.19C67.94,34.95,68,24,68,24S67.94,13.05,66.52,7.74z" fill="#000000" ></path><path d="M 45,24 27,14 27,34" fill="#0059dd"></path>
  </svg>
```

Comment: What exactly are you calling the border radius in your example?

Comment: The rounded corners.

Comment: The rounded corners don't have a constant radius, the differential changes in a piecewise continuous fashion.